# Unrecognised type - 'Error: Variable "[var-name]" is not a type name'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a class for handling physics as part of a project. We were told to use a class which handles arbitrary behaviours.

I've created a class which will update an internal state based on modules that are given to it (code follows). However, the structure representing the internal state, `PhysicsData`, isn't being recognised anywhere except its own file. Can anyone shed some light?

(Sorry for the massive dump of information, but the gap between the object being a problem and the place where it's a problem is quite large and trimming down the extra details also removes context that can be useful)

Here is the structure in question:

```
#pragma once

// This file "PhysicsBehaviourBase.h"

#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <vector>

struct PhysicsData
{
public:
    D3DXVECTOR3 velocity;
    D3DXVECTOR3 position;
    D3DXVECTOR3 rotation;
    float size;

    PhysicsData();
    void add(const PhysicsData& pd);
};
```

All references to `PhysicsData` in the rest of this file are fine. However this file starts to hint at problems:

```
#pragma once
// This file: "PhysicsBehaviours.h"

#include "PhysicsBehavioursBase.h"

class GravityConstant : public PhysicsBehaviour
{
private:
    float g; // Gravitational constant

    // Required by the PhysicsBehaviour interface.
    PhysicsBehaviour* copy() const {return new GravityConstant(g);}
public:
    GravityConstant(float accelleration_due_to_gravity = 9.81)
        : g(accelleration_due_to_gravity) {}

    // Required by the PhysicsBehaviour interface.
    void update(float time,const PhysicsData&, PhysicsData* out)
        {out->velocity.y -= g*time;}
};
```

In the `void update(float time,const PhysicsData&, PhysicsData* out)` line both references to `PhysicsData` are given the IntelliSense error message:

```
Physics PhysicsData 

Error: variable "PhysicsData" is not a type name.
```

I have no idea why IntelliSense think `PhysicsData` is a variable of type `Physics`. (`Physics` is a type I declare next, and `PhysicsData` is one of the parameters used to construct a physics object).

There is no compiler error at this point, however. The compiler error happens in the next file up the hierarchy:

```
#pragma once

// "Physics.h"

#include "Timing.h"
#include "PhysicsBehaviours.h"
#include <d3dx9.h> // For D3DXVECTOR3
#include <vector>

class Physics
{
private:
    std::vector<PhysicsBehaviour*> behaviours_;
    Timing timer;
    PhysicsData data;
    void addBehaviours(const BEHAVIOUR_LIST&);
public:
    Physics(const PhysicsData&,const BEHAVIOUR_LIST&);
    ~Physics() {}
    void update();
    PhysicsData state() const {return data;}
    float age() const {return timer.age();}
};
```

Both references to PhysicsData get the same IntelliSense error as above. Compiler errors point to this function:

```
#include "Physics.h"
// "Physics.cpp"

Physics(const PhysicsData& initalState,const BEHAVIOUR_LIST& behaviour) // Line 4
    : data(initialState) // Line 5
{ // Line 6
    addBehaviours(behaviour);
}
```

Compiler errors:

```
1>  Physics.cpp
1>[PATH]\physics.cpp(4): error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'PhysicsData'
1>[PATH]\physics.cpp(5): error C2065: 'initialState' : undeclared identifier
1>[PATH]\physics.cpp(6): error C2448: 'data' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
```

And more IntelliSense errors:
Underneath the `&` in `const PhysicsData&` from line 4:

```
Error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier.
```

Underneath the close bracket on line 4:

```
Error: expected a declaration.
```

Any clues, fixes or hypotheses are welcome.

Comment: Have you included Physics.h into Physics.cpp?

Comment: What does the PhysicsBehaviour class look like?  Is there more to the PhysicsBehaviourBase.h file?

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the class specifier from the constructor definition in `Physics.cpp`:

```
Physics::Physics(const PhysicsData& initalState,const BEHAVIOUR_LIST& behaviour)
^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: ... Just going to slap myself for missing an obvious one. I was too taken aback by the earlier IntelliSense errors I completely failed to check this.

Comment: Apparently a lot of other people missed it as well based on the number of views.