# Variable is not a type name error

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{                 
    cout << "hello world" << endl;                   
    return 0;
}
```

The code is as above, very simple example, but I get many errors like:

variable "_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE" is not a type name   Project2    d:\tools\VC\include\string.h    98

variable "errno_t" is not a type name   Project2    d:\tools\VC\include\crtdbg.h    848

and so on...

Image is here:
http://postimg.org/image/adhcs4p39/

Comment: How did you create this project in VS? ... Maybe try reinstalling VS.

Comment: Don't select pre-compiled headers when you create your project.

Comment: I did unclick the pre-complied headers but still the same errors

Comment: Visual Studio and C++ are details you provide in your tags, so it's not necessary to repeat them in your question title. The title should reflect something informative that is more than what the tags can convey. I've edited to make it more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unrecognised type - 'Error: Variable "\[var-name\]" is not a type name'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863487/unrecognised-type-error-variable-var-name-is-not-a-type-name)

Comment: This has nothing to do with class specifier....

Comment: ...it´s funny that both problems are Microsoft-specific things not working in Microsofts compiler, If not there, where else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image looks like VS2015, but the _CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE macro and errno_t type are not used or defined in the 2015 headers that I can find.  They are in the VS2012 headers (both are in crtdefs.h).  This looks like you are compiling against a mix of header files, with some from one compiler version and some from the other.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled 2012 version. Works like a magic!