# After update from vs15 to vs17 660 errors appeared

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I switched to a new laptop yesterday and decided to download the new VS 2017 Community. On my old laptop I used VS 2015 Enterprise. I've had multiple old projects giving me these errors. I have searched far and wide but the only relating question I could find:

[Variable is not a type name error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261867/variable-is-not-a-type-name-error)

Screenshot of error:

[image]

An example project where this is happening:

Source.cpp:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//Prototypes
int useFilter2D(int argc, char** argv);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    useFilter2D(argc,argv);

    waitKey(0);
}

Mat image_canny, image_gray_canny;
Mat dst, detected_edges;

int edgeThresh = 1;
int lowThreshold;
int const max_lowThreshold = 100;
int ratio = 3;
int kernel_size = 3;
char* window_name = "Result";

void CannyThreshold(int, void*)
{
    /// Reduce noise with a kernel 3x3
    blur(image_gray_canny, detected_edges, Size(3, 3));

    /// Canny detector
    Canny(detected_edges, detected_edges, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size);

    /// Using Canny's output as a mask, we display our result
    dst = Scalar::all(0);

    image_canny.copyTo(dst, detected_edges);
    imshow(window_name, dst);
}

int useFilter2D(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat src, src_gray;
    Mat grad;
    char* window_name = "Result Sobel";
    int scale = 1;
    int delta = 0;
    int ddepth = CV_16S;

    // Controle of er een argument aan het programma is meegegeven.
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    src = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    // Controleer of alles goed is gegaan
    if (!src.data)
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Laat de afbeelding zien in een apart window
    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window", src);

    // convert to grey
    GaussianBlur(src, src, Size(3, 3), 0, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // Create window 
    namedWindow(window_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    Mat grad_x, grad_y;
    Mat abs_grad_x, abs_grad_y;

    /// Gradient X
    Sobel(src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_x, abs_grad_x);

    /// Gradient Y
    Sobel(src_gray, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_y, abs_grad_y);

    /// Total Gradient (approximate)
    addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, grad);

    imshow(window_name, grad);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We cannot answer this without seeing a [mcve] of the code which is causing this. While you "can't imagine it being the code", we still need to see it. Maybe the compiler really is in error (unlikely), in which case we need the code to tell you how you might make it work. Or (more likely) the code is actually incorrect and used to work "by accident" (due to idisyncracies of VS < 2017), in which case we again need to see it to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Those are not compiler errors, but Intellisense not understanding the code. If you change the filter in the rightmost drop down list to build errors only, they will go away.

Comment: I added the code Angew thanks for notifying me. Also @BoPersson that was indeed the problem! Thanks i had been struggling with it for hours. It was targetting a windows 8.1 sdk that i didn't have.

Comment: @BoPersson That should be an answer, I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From the more of a guess in the comments, which turned out to be a solution:*

The errors shown in the image are not compiler errors, but IntelliSense not properly understanding the code. Strange as it might seem, IntelliSense is based on a separate compiler ([by EDG](http://edg.com/c)) that is not always totally in sync with the Visual C++ compiler.

If you change the filter in the rightmost drop down list from "Build  + IntelliSense" to "Build Only" errors, these messages will go away.